# Resolving DNS with winsock, with server behind router

Tags: c++, networking, dns, client-server, winsock

I recently started to play around with sockets in windows and I ran into a bit of trouble..
I have an application that I want to find a host with DNS name resolution (through an internet connection).

The program manages to resolve the DNS name to an IP address, but the IP address it finds is the one of the router that sits in front of the computer that runs the server application(which is what I expect, since it is the default gateway)..

My question would be if there is a way to connect to the server application without having to modify the router's settings by hand every time the server application is installed on a system that has a router sitting in front of it.. Or is the only way to do this to somehow forwarding the port of the computer to the router ?

Any help is appreciated!
Thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server is behind a router, then the router has to be configured for Port Forwarding.  There is no getting around that.  The router needs to know which machine on its network to forward incoming client requests to for any given port.  However, depending on the type of router and its features, the server app might be able to configure the Port Forwarding programmably using uPNP or SNMP, if available and enabled.  Otherwise, the router has to be configured by hand by the router admin.

Comment: Thank you, very useful! Is there any way to determine if the server is behind a router form c++? (So that it only tries to automatically forward the port if it is behind a router..)

Comment: There is no perfect way. But you can check if the local IP address is in RFC1918 space (such as 192.168.x.y, 10.x.y.x, and so on). If it is, you are definitely behind NAT. If it isn't you probably aren't.

Comment: I would have the server app query the machine's public IP using an external IP reporting service (such as `http://iplookup.flashfxp.com`, `http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp`, etc), then retreive the local machine's list of available IPs (using `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdapterAddresses()`), then check if the reported IP is found in that list.  If it is not, then the server machine is not directly connected to the Internet (that does not necessarily mean it is behind a router, though. It could be behind a proxy or ICS instead).